# Forcing browser to use "Save As ..." dialog box

Tags: http, internet-explorer, header

I would like a "Save As ..." dialog box to appear when a user clicks on a hyperlink.

I'm currently sending the HTTP headers:

application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: inline;filename=something.doc

Apparently IE users are seeing the page render inline as garbled ascii. What is the best way to force a "Save As ..." dialog box to pop up on IE?

Answer (score 7):

Try `Content-Disposition: Attachment`

Comment: A couple additional notes: You can add ";filename=(your filename)" to give the download a default file name (useful to avoid downloads with .aspx and .php extensions". Also, ensure that you have a non-zero expiry with anything that launches a download prompt - IE has a bug that will error out on downloads for anything set to immediately expire (might be fixed in 8, was definitely present in 7).

Comment: @Ryan: That remains true for HTTPS.